# How to expand elliptic curve public key from compressed form?

Tags: elliptic-curves, secp256k1

Following this page https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1, secp256k1 curve's equation is
$$y^2=x^3+7$$
Does this mean that I can substitute $G_x$ in the equation to get $G_y$?
I think yes and that's how public key compression works, since we don't actually need to store $y$ value because we can compute it at run-time. But after substitution of the generator point of secp256k1 I get wrong equation:
$$G_x = 0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798$$
$$G_y = 0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8$$
$$G_y^2=G_x^3+7$$
$$106736222501650227577219490950371...=1.66977061698153803977729810299616665e230 + 7$$
The equation is wrong. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ECC, all base arithmetic is performed on the $\mathbb F_p$. Secp256k1 used a prime so $\mod p$ is enough for these kind of operations. One needs a big integer library to calculate the arithmetic correctly. Here is a sample code from Sagemath

```
#secp256k1
p = Integer("0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F")

a = Integer("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
b = Integer("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007")

K = GF(p)
E = EllipticCurve(K,[a,b])

Gx = Integer(0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798)
Gy = Integer(0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8)
G = E(Gx, Gy)

# Check the base point
assert(Gy^2 % p == (Gx^3 + a * Gx + b) % p)

#Sample public points with compressed 02
Compressed = "02b4632d08485ff1df2db55b9dafd23347d1c47a457072a1e87be26896549a8737"
#Sample public points with compressed 03
#Compressed = "03b1e8e14e794c00c364daa5ff85258ac480a0e21e819e08d5a259553ed911cb15"

print( "Given public key\n", Compressed)

#lift to find point that has the given x coordinate
P = E.lift_x(Integer("0x"+Compressed[2:]))

#Determine the correct y-coordinate.

if (Integer(P[1]) % 2) == 0:
    print("Using compression 02\n", P)
else:
    Q = E(P[0],p-P[1])
    print("Using compression 03\n", Q)
```

The above code verifies the base point ( well, `G = E(Gx, Gy)` already has verification on SageMath), and there are two sample public keys to resolve the full point.

Keep in mind that

- prefix `04` means no compression
- prefix `02` means compression with $y$ coordinate is even
- prefix `03` means compression with $y$ coordinate is odd

The above code only handles the cases `02` and `03` not `04`.

Answer (score 2):

> Where am I going wrong?

The two sides are computed modulo a prime $p$.

For Secp256k1, we have $p = 2^{256}−2^{32}−977 = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663$

Computing them as integers or reals gives the wrong result, as you have seen.

And, to answer the question you have not asked, to compute $G_y$ from $G_x$, you need to do a modular square-root of $G_x^3 + 7$.  It turns out to not be that bad; because $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, the modular square roots of $z$ are $z^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$ and $p - z^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$, the latter sometimes is expressed as $- z^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$.

As so, we have $G_y = \pm (G_x^3 + 7)^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$ (and the compressed point should contain a bit that determines which of the two $G_y$ values to take).